# How to specify the macOS minimum SDK version when building Qt from source?

Tags: macos, qt, build

While building Qt from source, we need to specify the OSX minimal SDK version.

We tried to run the project `./configure`, then `export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="10.9"` before calling `make`.

The build procedure completed successfully.

Yet when we verify the minimal SDK version with:

```
otool -l lib/QtCore.framework/QtCore | grep LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX -A 5
```

the output is as follows:

```
      cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
  cmdsize 16
  version 10.10
      sdk 10.13
Load command 9
      cmd LC_SOURCE_VERSION
```

So the minimal SDK version is listed as 10.10, setting the `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` seems to have no effect.

Is there a way to actually specify this value for custom builds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum SDK version is set in file `qtbase/mkspecs/features/mac/default_post.prf` from the variable `QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`.

This variable value can be manually changed in the file `qtbase/mkspecs/macx-${compiler}/qmake.conf`

So the compilation procedure becomes:

1. `./configure`
2. Edit the `qmake.conf` file
3. `make`